# Is there an Ubuntu mini install

Tags: custom-distributions

Is there an installable ubuntu mini ISO that is just a command line?  I'm building a distro and I need to know.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) you can download minimal ISO's for a network installation. Note that you'll still need to download the packages, so this ISO's are meant to make installations in machines connected to the Internet.